# Can I lookup my Primary Key in SQL Server from Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: sql-server, import, sql-server-2016, excel

Disclaimer:  I'm a database novice teaching myself for a research project.

Background:  I am querying an electronic medical record (EMR) system for information pertinent to my project and I do not want to store medical record numbers (just say "no" HIPAA violations!). The database is designed with Visit_ID as a Primary Key and four fields which result in a unique combination: admission date & time, length of stay, admitting physician, and room number. All other information will be based on the Visit_ID. For example, the "Medications" table starts with Visit_ID as a Foreign Key and all other information such as start date, stop date, etc.

Problem:  The EMR system obviously does not know my Visit_ID. Therefore, all of my queries will have the four fields which are defined by Visit_ID in my database.

Question:  Can I resolve or lookup the Visit_ID within the database from the four columns in my Excel sheet?

Example:  I query the EMR for the medications the patients had in June. My query returns an Excel spreadsheet with my four fields (Admission Date & Time, Admitting Physician, Length of Stay, and Room) and all the necessary information about the medications. Can I import data from that Excel spreadsheet into my "Medications" table but have SQL Server resolve Visit_ID instead of keeping those four fields?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Excel can query data from a database. On the Data tab there are tools to [create and maintain](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-89D44137-F18D-49CF-953D-D22A2EEA2D46) connections. IIRC it uses ODBC so all major database products can be referenced.